# How to modify JOptionPane method in Java

Tags: java

Please, I need your help. Whenever I tried to run the below program, it will say incompatible types, String cannot be converted to Integer.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Addition
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     String num1 = (Integer)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num1");
     String num2 = (Integer)JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num2");

     String sum =
         (Integer)String.format("The sum is: %d", (num1 + num2));

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sum);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To expound on the other answers and show the code, here is what you need to make it work:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Addition
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     int num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num1"));
     int num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num2"));

     String sum = String.format("The sum is: %d", (num1 + num2));

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sum);
  }
}
```

You want to take the input from the JOptionPanes as an `int`s then add them and put the result in a `string`, not cast a `string` to an `int`.

NOTE: I wrote this on my mobile, so I’ll compile and run it when I get home, but above is the general idea.

Comment: Superb, meaning casting does not required here?

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to take an `int` in the first place.

`int num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane`...

And you can either do the same with the output, or parse it again.

Answer (score 0):

Its because your typecasting a String to an Integer and trying to store it in a String.

Remove (Integer) from the statement to get rid of that error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    int num1 =  Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num1"));
    int num2 =  Integer.valueOf(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num2"));

     String sum = String.format("The sum is: %d", (num1 + num2));

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's seems you want, something like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer num1 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num1"));
    Integer num2 = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter num2"));

    String sum = String.format("The sum is: %d", (num1 + num2));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sum);
}
```

Comment: Some more explanation would've been nice.

Comment: So happy with this development